# GWT Focus on TabLayOutPanel

Tags: gwt, gwt-tablayoutpanel

How do i set the focus on a TabLayoutPanel? I currently have two tabs and i need to programatically set the focus on one Tab.I figured out that there is not method in TabLayoutPanel API which supports this.

Also my 2nd question is , i need to move the focus from one tab to another when i hit the arrow button.If its right direction button on keyboard i need to move my tab focus to the next tab on the right and if its a left arrow button on keyboard i need to move the tab focus to the previous tab.

How can i implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

selectTab(int index) or selectTab(Widget child) should allow you to programmatically set the focus.

See: http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html